# Twilio-video prevents meteor app from starting on IE

Tags: meteor, twilio

Right now I'm using twilio-video.js with meteor, and it prevents the app from starting on IE. I know that twilio-video doesn't support IE calling, but on non-meteor builds it will just warn you, whereas on meteor it will prevent the app from starting.

This is the error that occurs: Unable to get property 'meteorInstall' of undefined or null reference

Removing twilio-video fixes this.

Comment: You need to add some client javascript to detect IE, and then not call the Twilio code that fails, and inform the user that it doesn't work in IE

Comment: @Mikkel the app breaks when all I do is import Video from 'twilio-video'

Comment: Maybe you can do a dynamic import of the video - the meteor guide has information about dynamic importing. That will give you a chance to detect the IE browser and not do the import

Comment: What is the code that you are using to include twilio-video that causes this breakage?

Comment: @philnash simply including `import Video from 'twilio-video'` breaks it. However, using twilio v1.0.0-beta2 fixes the problem, which is odd.

Comment: Were you using the release version before? Where are you importing twilio-video?

Comment: Yes I've been using the latest release and it has been working fine, except on IE as described. I'm importing it in one of my React components, pretty standard. @philnash

Comment: It just seems weird that twilio-vide would affect an object on which `meteorInstall` was being called. Especially only in one browser. Can you share some more code around this?

Comment: It can be reproduced as follows: install meteor, meteor create test, then cd into test and meteor npm install twilio-video, then add `import Video from 'twilio-video'` into the client. Even on a clean meteor build, it still breaks on IE.